# Двойная запись учёта задолженности Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Нужна подсказка для реализации двойной записи.

Веду магазин, даю вещи в долг, и сам временами занимаю, очень путаюсь, кому я должен, сколько кто мне должен, так как людей достаточно.

Есть главный лист, содержащий несколько столбцов: "расход", "доход", "лицо"(от которого поступает оплата).

Есть несколько других листов, называющиеся разными именами, допустим, "Вася", "Саша", "Женя", там будет только "расход" и "доход".

Условия задачи следующие:

1. Если на главной странице в столбце "расход" указать в ячейке сумму, а в столбце "лицо" выбрать из выпадающего списка имя (например, "Саша"), эта сумма перемещается на лист "Саша" в раздел "доход". С остальными листами то же самое. И если на главной странице указать сумму в столбце "доход" и выбрать лицо "Саша", то эта сумма переносится на лист "Саша" в столбец "расход" автоматически.
2. Если на любом листе, к примеру, "Вася" в столбце "расход" указать сумму, эта сумма переносится на главный лист в столбец "доход", а в столбце "лицо" будет указано имя "Вася". И также, если указать в столбце "доход" сумму, эта сумма переносится на главный лист в столбец "расход" и так же автоматически добавляется имя в столбце "лицо".

Как можно реализовать данную идею?

Была использована формула ЕСЛИ, но она помогает только с перемещениями суммы, но мне нужно связать так же и название листа со столбцом "лицо" на главном листе.

Comment: Данную идею можно реализовать на фриланс-площадке. Такие задачи допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код или формулы, которые вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Я использовал обычную формулу ЕСЛИ, но она работает, если ставить условия с одной ячейкой. Но у меня есть еще одно связующее, которое не работает с помощью ЕСЛИ - это связь со столбцом "лицо", я никак не могу подогнать автоматическое заполнение.

Comment: Писать и выяснять без ссылки на пример можно очень долго...

Comment: Судя по всему, вам нужно смотреть в сторону баз данных. Например, MS Access. Но сразу предупрежу - нужна хорошая теоретическая подготовка. В Excel решение данной задачи будет слишком сложным.